# tslint is being ignored when I am building a docker image

Tags: typescript, tslint, linter

I have a tslint file as such:

```
{
    "defaultSeverity": "error",
    "extends": [
        "tslint:recommended"
    ],
    "jsRules": {
        "object-literal-sort-keys": false
    },
    "rules": {
        "trailing-comma": [
            false
        ],
        "max-line-length": [
            false,
            250
        ],
        "no-console": "off",
        "only-arrow-functions": false,
        "no-empty": false,
        "object-literal-sort-keys": false,
        "prefer-const": false
    },
    "rulesDirectory": []
}
```

I am still in testing so I want some allowable amount of "messiness".

However when I try to build my docker file, and use npm run build, I get the following:

```
> tslint -c tslint.json -p tsconfig.json --fix

ERROR: /dir/src/controllers/customer/UserAPIController.ts:262:9 - Calls to 'console.log' are not allowed.
ERROR: /dir/src/controllers/customer/UserAPIController.ts:274:9 - Calls to 'console.log' are not allowed.
```

no-console is set to off - why is tslint choking on it?

This does not happen locally

EDIT: Dockerfile

```
FROM node:12

RUN set -x \
    rsyslog \
    bash \
    curl \
    wget \
    gettext \
    jq


RUN mkdir shoployal_admin

WORKDIR ./shoployal_admin
COPY . /shoployal_admin

RUN npm install -g typescript

RUN npm install

RUN npm run build

CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
EXPOSE 8080
```

Comment: It's hard to tell how this is relevant to docker given you didn't provide your dockerfile or anything.

Comment: @zerkms I don't think it is, but Dockerfile added

Comment: Would the version of typescript + tslint be the same on both your host machine (or wherever that check passes fine) and inside docker?

Comment: I think there's a slight discrepancy. I'll try getting them both on the same version.